# Refresh the browser between 2 tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, playframework, fluentlenium

I'm using FluentLenium with playframework.

How to refresh the browser between two test methods ?

And how to close the browser window at the end of the test suite ?

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh browser with Selenium `refresh` method

```
getDefaultDriver().navigate().refresh();
```

just use driver `close` method [to close the window](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/htmlunit/HtmlUnitDriver.html#close--)

```
getDefaultDriver().close()
```